# Sort numbers with decimals that are stored in string

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, stable-sort

I have numbers that are getting converted to string.
for example I have an amount 20000 and I have to show it as 200.00 so I am performing

```
string Amount = $"{Convert.ToDouble(x.Amount) / 100:0.00}"
```

and then I store them to list of amounts with values

> 200.00, 30.00, 588888.00, 56.36,

I tried sorting it by `orderby(x=>x.Anount)` but this sorts on basis of string with first number as

> 200.00, 30.00, 56.36, 58888.00

I want the output to be sorted as

> 30.00,
>   56.36,
>   200.00,
>   588888.00

Comment: sorts before convert to string or `OrderBy(x => double.Parse(x.Amount))`

Comment: Well, i  have a sorting page where i am sorting depending on each sort function using an ajax call. Is there anyother option i can convert it after storing in string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a custom comparer into OrderBy. [Enumerable.OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx) will let you specify any comparer you like.

```
void Main()
{
    string[] decimals = new string[] { "30.00", "56.36", "200.00", "588888.00" };

    foreach (var dec in decimals.OrderBy(x => x, new DecimalComparer()))
    {    
        Console.WriteLine(thing);
    }
}


public class DecimalComparer: IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string s1, string s2)
    {
        if (IsDecimal(s1) && IsDecimal(s2))
        {
            if (Convert.ToDecimal(s1) > Convert.ToDecimal(s2)) return 1;
            if (Convert.ToDecimal(s1) < Convert.ToDecimal(s2)) return -1;
            if (Convert.ToDecimal(s1) == Convert.ToDecimal(s2)) return 0;
        }

        if (IsDecimal(s1) && !IsDecimal(s2))
            return -1;

        if (!IsDecimal(s1) && IsDecimal(s2))
            return 1;

        return string.Compare(s1, s2, true);
    }

    public static bool IsDecimal(object value)
    {
        try {
            int i = Convert.ToDecimal(value.ToString());
            return true; 
        }
        catch (FormatException) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: int i = Convert.ToDecimal(value.ToString());   ??   Decimal.TryParse is probably a little more efficient than catching and error

Comment: Absolutely agree. It was a simple example. But, definitely, I could be written more efficiently.

Comment: Also moving the `Convert.ToDecimal` out of the `if` statement and just keeping the result in a variable then reusing the variable 3 times would be another improvement

Answer (score 0):

try

orderby(x=>double.Parse(x.Amount))

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var numberstring = "100.0,300.00,200.00,400.00";
var array = numberstring.Split(',');
var sortedstring = array.OrderBy(x => double.Parse(x)).Aggregate("", (current, val) => current + (val + ","));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line:

```
        var orderedAsString =
            amounts.Select(x => double.Parse(x.Amount) / 100)
                .OrderBy(x => x)
                .Select(x => x.ToString("0.00"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can sort by the Length property which will provide the desired order. For example:

```
        IEnumerable<string> sizes = new List<string> { "200.00", "30.00", "56.36", "58888.00" };

        sizes = sizes.OrderBy(x => x.Length);
```