# Easy way sorting list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of objects that i need to sort by the field "IST".
The field "IST" always holds numeric values but somehow the developer designed it to be of type string.

Example:

- Dsrm.IST = "5";
- Dsrm.IST = "10";
- Dsrm.IST = "2";
- Dsrm.IST = "3";
- Dsrm.IST = "1";
- Dsrm.IST = "22";

when i use

```
var temp = Dsrm.OrderBy(x => x.IST);
```

The sort is not correct.
Is there an easy solution to solve this.

And no, im not allowed to change the definition of the table.

Comment: var temp = Dsrm.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.IST));

Comment: `var temp = Dsrm.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.IST));`

Comment: When you cast however, verify that you do indeed have a number literal inside. Otherwise you will get an exception.

Comment: Do we really need this question thousands of times here? Just a short search for "sort list of numbers stored in strings", e.g. this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746496/sort-numbers-with-decimals-that-are-stored-in-string

Comment: `Dsrm.OrderBy(x => x.IST.Length).ThenBy(x => x.IST)`

Comment: Thank you all, sorry for the stupid question, but as mentioned, sometimes working under stress hide all visions, but i learned that linq can accept many functions :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Convert.ToInt32` (not sure if your LINQ provider supports `int.Parse`)

```
var temp = Dsrm.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.IST));
```

Of course that is less efficient and less safe than using the correct type in the first place.

Comment: Thank you Tim, sometimes simple solutions is not visible when working under stress. didn't expect that linq will accept Convert.Toin32.
Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is a string it's little bit difficult, I would implement a custom `IComparer<T>` class. From what I can gather, the structure of the items is either a number, of a combination of a number followed by a letter(s). If this is the case, the following `IComparer<T>` implementation should work

```
public class CustomComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var regex = new Regex("^(d+)");

        // run the regex on both strings
        var xRegexResult = regex.Match(x);
        var yRegexResult = regex.Match(y);

        // check if they are both numbers
        if (xRegexResult.Success && yRegexResult.Success)
        {
            return int.Parse(xRegexResult.Groups[1].Value).CompareTo(int.Parse(yRegexResult.Groups[1].Value));
        }

        // otherwise return as string comparison
        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```

With this `IComparer<T>`, you'll be able to sort your list of string by doing

```
var myComparer = new CustomComparer();
var temp.Sort(myComparer);
```

Comment: If you want to validate the string first you could use `int.TryParse` instead of an regex.

Comment: The OP says "The field "IST" always holds numeric values" so I'm not sure where you got the idea there might be letters in there (unless I missed something). Assuming it is always numeric this is a little overkill...

Comment: @Chris The OP said "IST" allways holds numberic values, but as you can see it's a string, it may be a case someone could provide empty strings or some kind of character, and what's gonna happen? Let application fall down because we didn't think about all cases.. I could simply do Convert.ToInt32("ISTVALUE"); but imagine empty string there instead of zero or whatever, I don't know maybe it's overkill but I like to do it this way...

Comment: @Roxy'Pro: In the case that there is a possibility that there is non-numeric data I'd agree that this is probably useful. If it is specified that the data is always numeric (even though its a string) then in my view finding something non-numeric is an error and should throw an exception or at the very least not just continue as if everything is fine. (As a note I don't disagree enough to downvote, I just don't think this is the best answer to the question).